# Using keychain to store username and password in xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, keychain

I don't want to use `NSUserDefaults` as I have been told it's not a good way to save a username and password.

So I was going to use a Keychain, but I have never used them before. Can some one please just a give a quick example of one or point me in the direction of an example ? Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I Use the open source [SSKeychain](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain) wrapper around the the C api used by the keychain.

It's convenient, easy to use, and works on Mac OS and iOS.

Comment: +1 for great wrapper. Will this work on the simulator as well?

Comment: Works for me when I'm testing on the simulator.

Comment: I asked because I have heard that generic keychain for ios does not work on simulator. Is sskeychain a wrapper for geenricKeychain? if yes than even it should not work.. ?

Comment: @Abizern it says that it doesn't support in MAC 10.6 Does it support in Mac 10.7.4?

Comment: That's what it generally means when people specify support. If it doesn't support 10.6 it supports everything later than that.

Answer (score 4):

This is the best I have found till date... It five a very simple implementation of saving passwords and username to keychain. Please remember to include security framework in your project.

https://web.archive.org/web/20160305031351/http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html

Keep in mind that this doen't work on simulator.

Comment: The SSKeychain mentioned by Abizem seems the best option to me as it is very easy to implement.